# PostgreSQL - JSON column remove attribute inside an array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a jsonb column in PostgreSQL and what I want to do is retrieve the values in this columns, but exclude an attribute that is inside an array.

From what I can find it's required for an index to be included in the query so the best I've been able to do is remove the attribute from only a single item in the array.

Example of what I currently have

```
SELECT jsonb '[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}]' #- '{0,"b"}';
```

Current output

```
[{"a": 1}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
```

Desired output

```
{"a": 1}
{"a": 3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out what I needed to do.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb '[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}]') - 'b';
```

Output

```
{"a": 1}
{"a": 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator twice:

```sql
select jsonb '[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}]' #- '{0,"b"}' #- '{1, "b"}';
```

If you want to remove an unknown number of `"b"` attributes, you need to unnest the array and rebuild it:

```sql
select jsonb_agg(value - 'b')
from jsonb_array_elements(jsonb '[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}]')
```

You can consider creating a handy function:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_remove_attribute_from_array(jsonb, text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_agg(value - $2)
    from jsonb_array_elements($1)
$$;

select jsonb_remove_attribute_from_array('[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":4}]', 'b');
```

[Db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dcadb363f3ccab578611f347e4701d31)

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the original question I wrote the "desired output" in the wrong format (one row instead of multiple rows). For my original output, your solution works perfectly but it isn't the solution for what I intended the output to be.